# Unable to get typeahead working in my fiddle

Tags: javascript, typeahead.js

I am just working my way out with implementing the [Twitter's typeahead plugin](http://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/) in my fiddle. However I am getting an error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

This error is on the line where I am mentioning `ttAdapter()`. But I see `ttAdapter()` is already mentioned in [the plugin](http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/typeahead.js/0.10.2/typeahead.bundle.min.js).

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rdesai/Ca4rq/1/)

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were missing Bloodhound suggestion integration, which has to be instantiated with `.initialize()`.

http://jsfiddle.net/Ca4rq/2/ should be what you're after.
Adapted from https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/examples/